# Движение верхней панели сайта при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Хочу реализовать движение верхней панели сайта при прокрутке с помощью html, css(и если это возможно без java script). Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в Css того блока что должен плавать

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: А если хочу чтобы блок в каком-то месте откреплялся и оставался на странице? В таком случае без js не обойтись?

Comment: Не много не понял вас.

Comment: Что конкректно вам нужно? Чтобы блок прикрепился к части экрана или нет?

Comment: Или же доходил до определенного места(маячка, якоря) и сбрасывал css правило? Если да,  то без js действительно не обойтись.

Comment: Вот ссылка -http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/09/scroll-block.html  -там есть пример. Админ прости - писать весь код лень.

Comment: Именно это. Спасибо.